# White line between background image in Edge Chromium

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

I have the following simple CSS table that I created at http://www.cssdesk.com/fWHGe

When you view this via Chrome or IE you see it displays normal.

[image]

However, when I view it in the new Edge Chromium browser, there is this annoying white line in between.  Do you know the default Edge browser CSS somehow caused this?

I notice when I zoom in or out on the browser (Edge Chromium), at certain level this white line disappears, but I can see the white line at 100%.  My screen resolution is 1920x1080

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to test the issue on my side. My screen resolution is 1920x1080. I make a test on Win 10, MS Edge Chromium browser and Google Chrome browser.

I noticed that when the zoom is 100% both browsers showing a similar result with no white line.

[image]

I noticed that when I tried to zoom in or zoom out, both browsers show the white line at some point.

[image]

I also make a test with the IE 11 and firefox browser and this issue is not there. So we can say that this issue is related to Chromium browsers.

I tried to make tests with some CSS code to fix this issue but the issue persists for Chromium browsers. As a workaround, I suggest you can refer an example below for creating a split button that does not cause this issue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
.btn {
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;

}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.btn:hover, .dropdown:hover .btn {
  background-color: #0b7dda;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button class="btn">Button</button>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn">
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Reference:

[Split Button Dropdowns](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_button_split.asp)

Further, you can modify the example based on your own requirements.

Comment: Thank you, I will try out your suggestion but I wonder if there is a place to raise this as a bug with Chromium because it should be backward compatible.   The example I use is simple but our real application is litter with this issue and it may prevent us from officially support Edge Chromium if the turn around dev time for this fix is too long :(

Comment: I will try to submit your feedback regarding this issue via an internal channel. Thanks for your understanding.